# OpenCV-3.0.0-beta missing xfeatures2d submodule (Python3.4)

Tags: python, opencv, shared-libraries

I am trying to use OpenCV 3.0 with Anaconda Python3.4. I compiled the opencv sources from Github together with the accompanying opencv_contrib repository and installed them inside a local directory.

Now, starting python I am able to import the cv2 module and do stuff like loading and displaying images. However it seems that the submodule xfeatures2d doesn't exist.

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.xfeatures2d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'
```

Interestingly I get no error if I try to `import cv2.xfeatures2d` (although I still can't use it then)

The shared library file exists in `~/MyOpenCV3Install/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.3.0.0`. My first guess was that it is not being loaded for some reason, so I tried to force it using the `LD_PRELOAD` environment  variable prior to launching python. However still no luck so far.

For me it doesn't work using the python3.4 environment. However, when using a python2.7 environment everything works just fine. After importing the cv2 module I can call functions like `cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()` without errors.

Does anybody have an idea why the xfeatures2d submodule is not available when using python3.4? Is it possible that the python bindings created for opencv_contrib are not compatible with python3 yet?

EDIT:

I used the following options for the cmake configuration step:

```
BUILD_opencv_python3=ON
PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/home/mi/anaconda/envs/env3.4/bin/‌​python3.4
PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/mi/anaconda/envs/env3.4/include/python3.4.m‌​
PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/home/mi/anaconda/envs/env3.4/lib/libpython3.4m.so
PYTHON3_N‌​UMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/mi/anaconda/envs/env3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/‌​core/include
PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/mi/anaconda/envs/env3.4/lib/python3.4/‌​site-packages
```

Comment: AFAIK, one of the points of the 3.0 release was full Python 3.x compatibility. Did you compile OpenCV specifically with python3, or did you just use python?

Comment: I used the following options for the cmake configuration step

Comment: `BUILD_opencv_python3=ON`,`PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/home/mi/anaconda/envs/env3.4/bin/python3.4`,`PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/mi/anaconda/envs/env3.4/include/python3.4.m`,`PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/home/mi/anaconda/envs/env3.4/lib/libpython3.4m.so`,`PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/mi/anaconda/envs/env3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include`,`PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/mi/anaconda/envs/env3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages`. Using basic OpenCV3 functionality actually works with python3.4, the problem seems to be with parts from the opencv_contrib repository.